# How to print a calculated value into a message box?

Tags: python, python-3.9

I am trying to print a calculated value, which is stored in "remainder" and print it into a message box. However, I am getting an error which states
messagebox.showinfo('Alert','Current levels dropped by',remainder)
TypeError: showinfo() takes from 0 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given. I was wondering if anyone could help me out here, thank you so much. The code is as shown below.

```
quotient = c1/800
percent = quotient * 100
remainder = 100 - percent
alarmlight = my_canvas.create_oval(50, 50, 100, 100, fill='green')
my_canvas.itemconfig(alarmlight, fill="red") #Fill the circle with red
window = Tk()
window.eval('tk::PlaceWindow %s center' % window.winfo_toplevel()) #window will be infront of all windows
window.withdraw()
messagebox.showinfo('Alert','Current levels dropped by',remainder)
```

Comment: You need `messagebox.showinfo('Alert','Current levels dropped by' + remainder)`

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA Thanks. However, i tried it and this is the error shown. messagebox.showinfo('Alert','Current levels dropped by'+remainder)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "numpy.float64") to str

Comment: ```messagebox.showinfo('Alert',f'Current levels dropped by {remainder}')```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to use `f-strings`

```
messagebox.showinfo('Alert',f'Current levels dropped by {remainder}')
```

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solves your issue @PythonBeginner